# Can Snow Tiger Berserker let me charge past someone and full attack them?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, charge

**Pounce** lets me make a full attack in the end of a charge.

**Dive Attack** works like a charge.

**Flyby Attack** lets me take a move action, including a dive and a standard action. I must be misunderstanding here or can I charge (dive) and make a standard action?

**Snow Tiger Berserker** says

> You may make a full attack as part of a charge action, but only if you are armed with a light weapon.

If I used Snow Tiger Berserker instead of Pounce, can I charge past someone and full attack, as it is part of a charge? Combined with the other feats, perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

## Dive attacks are almost identical to charges in all ways except those listed

Dive attacks require more movement (30 ft. horizontal and 10 ft. vertical, instead of just 10 ft. horizontal for a charge), and only let you use claw or talon attacks, no others. Furthermore, those claw and talon attacks have their damage doubled.

For every other conceivable concern, “*a dive attack works just like a charge.*” That includes working with Pounce or Snow Tiger Berserker, so yes, you could perform a dive attack and then have a full-attack if you have either of these.

However, dive attacks are also like charges in other ways: they take a full-round action, and they require that you move in a straight line.

Furthermore, a *dive* and a *dive attack* are different things. You can dive without attacking, and that is a move action. Fly-by Attack allows you to perform such a dive with a standard action taking place somewhere in the middle of the dive. But this is not a dive attack: that is a full-round action, and Fly-by Attack does not allow you to do anything in particular with those.

So yes, you can combine a dive attack and Snow Tiger Berserker, but you cannot use Fly-by Attack when you do.

Comment: Pre-congratulations on 100k Rep KRyan!

Answer (score 2):

### Charge doesn't work that way.

On the 3.5 SRD the text for [Charge](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/specialAttacks.htm#charge) states the following:

> **Movement During a Charge**
>
> You must move before your attack, **not after.** You must move at least 10
>   feet (2 squares) and may move up to double your speed directly toward
>   the designated opponent.

For the functions of Pounce or Snow Tiger Berserker, Your Charge (Which is normally a full-round action) allows you to also make a full attack after you have concluded your movement. You aren't able to move after you complete a charge.

The description for Fly states:

> A creature that flies can make dive attacks. A dive attack works just like a charge, but the diving creature must move a minimum of 30 feet and descend at least 10 feet. It can make only claw or talon attacks, but these deal double damage. A creature can use the run action while flying, provided it flies in a straight line.

Meaning that like Charge, A dive attack is a Full-Round action that completes your movement when the attack is begin. After the attack you can no longer make any more movement for the remainder of the round.

[Flyby Attack](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsterFeats.htm) states:

> When flying, the creature can take a move action (including a dive) and another standard action at any point during the move. The creature cannot take a second move action during a round when it makes a flyby attack.

What this means is that you can take a move action, pathing your movement through or near a targets cell, use your standard action during your movement to launch an attack, and then complete your movement. The Flyby Attack feat specifically states that you may not make a second move, nor does it state that the feat incorporates a charge in any way. The Move action section of the feat states that you can make a Dive, but a Dive Attack isn't a move action, it's a full-round action, so the effects of Flyby Attack don't function in conjunction with Dive Attack.

### What does that mean?

There's no combination of feats that will let you move past someone and make a full-round attack at the same time that I am currently aware of. Spring Attack and Flyby attack allow you to attack during your move, but they cannot be used in conjunction with Pounce. And Since the Dive Attack action directly specifies that it uses only Claw or Talon attacks, its an action which references monsters, which are governed by [natural weapons](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#naturalWeapons), and are limited to one per round anyway.

Comment: You are completely correct about this, except an answer here really does need to address dive attack vs. charge. Furthermore, the recommendation of Spring Attack is confusing; it doesn’t help here (and if it did, Fly-by Attack would help *more* since it is a strictly-superior feat).

Comment: @KRyan [Objection!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenix_Wright:_Ace_Attorney) The feat [Flyby Attack](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsterFeats.htm#flybyAttack) doesn't provide a flying melee-only creature (which is, actually, more than a few) protection from its targets's attacks of opportunity the way the feat [Spring Attack](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#springAttack) does.